# Probability of success given another success (conditional probability problem)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that independent students have to solve a homework. Student A solves the homework with a probability of $70\%$, Student B solves it with a probability of $80\%$ and Student C solves it with a probability of $90\%$.

**a)** What is the probability that all the students solve the homework if at least two students solve the homework?

**b)** What is the probability that Student B solves the homework if less than two students solve the homework?

**c)** What is the probability that less than two students solve the homework?

I have tried this procedure:

**a)** There are three possible cases:

- Student B and C have already solved the homework, and so student A has yet to solve the problem ($70\%$)
- Student A and C have already solved the homework, and so student B has yet to solve the problem ($80\%$)
- Student A and B have already solved the homework, and so student C has yet to solve the problem ($90\%$)

The probability of the first event is ($80\% * 90\% = 72\%$), for the second is ($70\% * 90\% = 63\%$), for the third is ($70\% * 80\% = 56\%$).
So the result is: ($70\% * 72\%$) + ($80\% * 63\%$) + ($90\% * 56\%$) but the result is unrealistic ($151.2\%$). What is wrong?

**b)** I had in mind to use a procedure very similar to point **a)** but I believe that I get an wrong result

**c)** The overall probability is given by:
($70\% * 20\% * 10\%$) + ($30\% * 80\% * 10\%$) + ($30\% * 20\% * 90\%$) = $9.2\%$
Is it correct?

Comment: The probability that someone here will solve your homework presented like this is rather low! It's frowned upon to present questions (especially homework) without showing your attempts. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried before asking questions here.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I edited the first post :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that by team $A$, you meant student $A$, and similarly for $B,C$.

Define events $A,B,C,X,Y$ as

- $A$ is the event that student $A$ solves the homework.$\\[4pt]$

  $B$ is the event that student $B$ solves the homework.$\\[4pt]$

  $C$ is the event that student $C$ solves the homework.$\\[4pt]$

  $X$ is the event that all three students solve the homework.$\\[4pt]$

  $Y$ is the event that at least two students solve the homework.

and for any event $E$, let $E'$ denote the complementary event "$\text{not}\,E$".

Then we have
$$
P(X)=P(A)P(B)P(C)=\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{9}{10}=\frac{63}{125}=.504
$$
and  
\begin{align*}
P(Y)&=
P(A\cap B\cap C')
\,+\,
P(B\cap C\cap A')
\,+\,
P(C\cap A\cap B')
\,+\,
P(A\cap B\cap C)
\\[4pt]
&=
\left(\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{10}\right)
+
\left(\frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{10}\right)
+
\left(\frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{5}\right)
+
\left(\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{9}{10}\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{451}{500}
=
.902
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
For parts $(a)$ and $(b)$, you need to apply the formula for conditional probability.

**Part $(a)$:**$\;$The probability that all three students solve the homework given that at least two students solve the homework is
$$
P(X|Y)
=
\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}
=
\frac{P(X)}{P(Y)}
=
\frac
{\left({\large{\frac{63}{125}}}\right)}
{\left({\large{\frac{451}{500}}}\right)}
=
\frac{252}{451}
\approx
.5587583149
$$
**Part $(b)$:**$\;$The probability that student $B$ solves the homework given that less than two students solve the homework is
$$
P(B|Y')
=
\frac{P(B\cap Y')}{P(Y')}
=
\frac{P(B\cap C'\cap A')}{P(Y')}
=
\frac
{
\left(
{\large{\frac{4}{5}}}
\cdot
{\large{\frac{1}{10}}}
\cdot
{\large{\frac{3}{10}}}
\right)
}
{\left({\large{\frac{49}{500}}}\right)}
=
\frac{12}{49}
\approx
.2448979592
$$
For part $(c)$, you were on the right track but you missed the case where none of the three students solve the homework.

But since we've already computed $P(Y)$, there's an easier way . . .

**Part $(c)$:**$\;$The probability that less than two students solve the homework is
$$
P(Y')
=
1-P(Y)
=
1-\frac{451}{500}
=
\frac{49}{500}
=
.098
$$

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and I've edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks for the full explanation. Ciao!